# Nao consigo fazer um contador de cliques em um JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Estou a desenvolver um "jogo", onde há um botão na tela e o jogador tem de clicar varias vezes no botão para ganhar dinheiro. Para isso, estou a fazer uma espécie de contador de cliques, onde a variável `xi` é a quantidade de cliques, e a quantidade de cliques é equivalente ao dinheiro que o jogador tem.

O problema é que, quando eu clico uma vez no botão, a variável `xi` passa para um, como é suposto, mas depois o contador para de contar os cliques (como se o limite de cliques fosse 1. Como é que eu mudo o limite de cliques para infinito?

E eu não estou a usar o netBeans para criar a janela, estou a fazer tudo em código.

```
package getRich;


import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class rich extends JFrame{


    private JLabel label;
    private JButton button;
    private JLabel label1;

    public rich() {

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        label1 = new JLabel("Hey!! Wellcome to get rich!! The game is simple... GET RICH!");
        add(label1);

        label = new JLabel("Your money: 0");
        add(label);


        button = new JButton("Click me to get MONEY!!");
        add(button);


        but but = new but();
        button.addActionListener(but);

    }


    public class but implements ActionListener{
        int xi = 0;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent but){


            for(xi=0; xi<=1; xi++){
            label.setText("Your money: " + xi);
            }

        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {        

    rich gui = new rich();

    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setVisible(true);
    gui.setSize(500, 500);
    gui.setTitle("Get Rich");


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E altere seu método listener para:

```
class but implements ActionListener{

    private int xi;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent but){

        xi++;
        label.setText("Your money: " + xi);

    }

}
```

Atente-se também a convenção de nomenclatura do java, onde classes devem iniciar com letra maiúscula.

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Ja funciona!